# Simulating button click in logon page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use jquery to trigger (click) a button on a logon page. Standard javascript works:

```
document.getElementById('loginButton').click();
```

However, when using jquery like this nothing happens.

```
$("#loginButton").click();
```

I've tested that jquery is working and can find the loginButton using this.

```
console.log($("#loginButton").length) which returns a 1.
```

Comment: put your code within a try catch block and alert error message inside catch, to see if there is any error

Comment: can u give us a jsfiddle link?

Comment: Its hard to provide a jsfiddle link since I'm injecting jquery into an existing DOM. I know jquery is woking properly because eveyrthing else I'm using it for works. Its just this button that doesn't seem to work

Comment: have u debugged your code with firebug or ...?
are you sure your code dosnt have any error?

Comment: Yes - no errors that I can see.

Comment: i think no one can solve this problem but yourself :)

Comment: Yes agreed - its a strange one.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("loginbutton").trigger("click");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call that click function:

```
$( "#target" ).click();
```

Comment: Yes - I tried that. Still doesn't work. I updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

OK So this was what I needed to do for jquery to work.

```
 $("#loginButton")[0].click();
```

Strange because `document.getElementById('loginButton').click()` worked fine as it was. Can anyone explain why this might be ?